# Marcar dia de cada semana repetindo um número de vezes

Tags: php, data

Estou fazendo uma agenda e preciso criar um formulário onde se repita um número de vezes o dia de cada semana.

Exemplo:

Hoje dia 09/11/2018

Quero que repita 3 vezes o dia da semana ficando assim?

**09/11/2018**

**16/11/2018**

**23/11/2018**

Meu código está assim, mas não estou conseguindo, utilizei o for como estrutura de repetição. Como poderia fazer isso?

```
for ($contador = 0; $contador < 3; $contador++) {

    $data2 = str_replace("-", "/", date('Y-m-d'));

$data= date('d/m/Y', strtotime($data2));     

echo $data."<br>";  

$data = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data);
$data->add(new DateInterval('P7D')); // 7dias
echo $data->format('d/m/Y');

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O algoritmo é simples, você precisa:

1. Criar uma data inicial
2. Printar data
3. Adiciona 1 semana
4. Volta ao passo 2 até que as repetições seja suficientes

Exemplo:

```
<?php

$hoje = new DateTime();
$semana = new DateInterval('P7D');
$repeticoes = 3;

do {
    echo $hoje->format('d/m/Y') . "\n";  // Printa data
    $hoje = $hoje->add($semana);         // Adiciona uma semana
} while (--$repeticoes);
```

<sup>[Repl.it com código funcionando](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/MountainousGoodnaturedLocatorprogram)</sup>

Comment: Alterei para utilizar o laço `do {...} while()`. Faz mais sentido neste contexto